# Exception in existing Java project

Tags: java

I have checked out an existing Java project, and I'm not sure how to fix this error I'm seeing(newbie):

```
public SessionBean getSessionBean() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{sessionBean}", SessionBean.class);
}
```

the error message on the return line:

The type javax.el.ELException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I'm not seeing any class file in the project, maybe I need to build the project?

Comment: Did you read the linked duplicate? It was the first result when I searched for the error you have given.

Comment: Yes, but, when it comes to add the library, I don't see any JBoss Rutime in Server Runtime after JBoss installed